# Sci-fi/horror movie: recreating the moment life first appeared on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi film that involved scientists investigating the moment that life first arose in the prebiotic conditions (the "primordial soup") of early Earth. The story involved filling a pressure chamber with chemicals and zapping it with electricity to simulate lightning. Of course, having succeeded in creating life, things take a turn for the worse as the new life-form wreaks havoc.

I saw this movie in the UK, probably in the 1970s, perhaps a little later. I suspect it was B&W and made in the US, but I can't be certain on either of those points. The storyline seems to have been based on the (real life) Miller-Urey experiment on abiogenesis which took place in the early 1950s, so presumably it was produced after that.

Comment: How those lifeform looked like? Where was that lab located? (Earth, another planet?). Our time, future?

Comment: Similar to [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lzjqwMpv90](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lzjqwMpv90)?

Comment: The setting was real-world, contemporary with its production, so ~1950s Earth. I'm afraid don't remember the life-form, or even if it was ever shown. The film you suggest may be similar in concept but was made much later.

Comment: Carl Sagan from *Cosmos* on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2xly_5Ei3U

Comment: There was an episode of the TV series Science Fiction Theatre (1955) that involved this set up - riffing on the Urey experiment, which they perform in the episode with lightning and chemicals to make "bugs": https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0696262/

Comment: There was an episode of Invaders (I think it was called "Genesis") that was similar, too, though the "monster" never got out of the lab.

Comment: @Cassfrank/@moopet. It's entirely possible that what I saw was an episode of a series rather than a movie, so I'll check out your suggestions. The "thanks in advance" was removed from my question (I guess civility is frowned upon), but I'm a contrary English knave, so I will repeat: thank you both for your help, it is appreciated.

Comment: Could this be from the Outer Limits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_359_(The_Outer_Limits)

Comment: @Parker. Thanks for the suggestion, another one for me to check out.